# On $\sum_{\substack{1\leq d\leq x\\(d,r)=1}}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}W(\frac{x}{d})$, with $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function and $W(x)$ the Lambert $W$ function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics

I wondered if it is possible to posed a similar question than **Question 2** by Olivier Ramaré from [1] (page 231), although the computational evidence that I have for my conjecture is very small.

**Conjecture.** *For all* $x\geq 1$ *and for all integers* $r\geq 1$ *one has that*
$$0\leq \sum_{\substack{1\leq d\leq x\\(d,r)=1}}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}W(\frac{x}{d})\tag{1}$$
*where here* $\mu(n)$ *denotes the Möbius function and* $W(z)$ *denotes the main branch of the Lambert* $W$ *function.*

As reference I know that Wikipedia has the articles with titles [*Möbius function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) and [*Lambert* $W$ *function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

> **Question.** I would like to know if you can find a counterexample* (an integer) $x$ and its  corresponding $r$, or show what work can be done about the veracity of previous conjecture. **Many thanks.**

*If you are able to find a counterexample easily please try to state/prove an inequality with good mathematical content of the type $C\leq \sum_{\substack{1\leq d\leq x\\(d,r)=1}}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}W(\frac{x}{d})$, being this your inequality true for a suitable constant $C$ and $\forall x\geq 1$ and $\forall r\geq 1$.

If my problem/question is very difficult, after there are some contributions I should consider accepting an available answer.

### References:

[1] Olivier Ramaré, *Some elementary explicit bounds for two mollifications of the Moebius function*, Funct. Approx. Comment. Math. Volume 49, Number 2 (2013), pp 229-240.

Comment: I know the reference [1] from **Project Euclid**. I hope that my **Question** is clear, interesting and at research level, please feel free to add your feedback in comments. On the other hand as was said my computational evidence is very small, thus please if you can to get easily a counterexample I am looking for an answer for **the asterisk question** in penultimate paragraph **as an alternative question**, with the purpose that the post is more interesting.

Comment: I think that my problem is interesting as a comparison to Ramaré's **Question 2** that I refer from the first paragraph in page 231 of [1], since the main/principal branch of the  Lambert $W$ function is an important function with an asymptotic behaviour related to the logarithm, see the section *Asymptotic expansions* from the linked article dedicated to the function Lambert $W$. Also are arising, in recent years, articles from the literature about analytic number theory and some branchs of the Lambert $W$.